# Simplify Boolean Function with don't care

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, karnaugh-map

Can you help me with this problem:

"Simplify the Boolean Function together with the don't care condition d in sum of the products and product of sum.

```
F(x,y,z) = ∑(0,1,2,4,5)
d(x, y, z) = ∑(3,6,7)"
```

I try to solve it but I came up with 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Karnaugh map for this problem. The order of the minterms would be (in the top row), 0,2,6,4 and (in the bottom row) 1, 3, 7, 5. This evaluates to 1 since the 'don't cares' can be whatever value (1 or 0).

|*1*|_1_|*d*|_1_|

| 1 | d | d | 1 |

Comment: i.e. it is a 3-input function and all the outputs are either 1 or don't cares which can be simplified to 1 since the rest of the outputs are 1.

Comment: I used karnaugh map too, but I have a different illustration..
The top row is (0, 1, 3, 2) and the bottom row is (4, 5, 7, 6)
|1|1|1|X|
|1|1|X|X|

Comment: That is a valid K-map as well. You set X as the columns and YZ as the rows of the map. I used Z as my columns which shouldn't matter as long as the numbers in the squares are correct. Although, I believe your top row should be |1|1|X|1|.